# How to read in all excel files (with multiple sheets) in a folder without specifying the excel names (Python)?

Tags: python, excel, pandas, dataframe, directory

I need to read in about 100 excel files under the same folder. Each file name contains a company name starting with an identifying number (e.g. 1CompanyA, 2CompanyB) and each of them has 10 same tab names (sheet1, sheet2, ....sheet10).

This [website](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-read-all-excel-files-under-a-directory-as-a-pandas-dataframe/) shows how to read all files (with a single sheet) under a directory as a Pandas DataFrame. However, I wonder if there's a way to read in multiple sheets under the same situation. It would also be nice if the read-in dataframes can be named as `starting number of the company`+`sheet_name`. For example, sheet1 of `1CompanyA.xlsx` would be assigned to dataframe `c1_sheet1` (c stands for company)

Here's the code to read all files (with a single sheet) under a directory as a Pandas DataFrame.

```
# import necessary libraries
import pandas as pd
import os
import glob
  
  
# use glob to get all the csv files
# in the folder
path = os.getcwd()
csv_files = glob.glob(os.path.join(path, "*.xlsx"))
  
  
# loop over the list of csv files
for f in csv_files:
    
    # read the csv file
    df = pd.read_excel(f)
      
    # print the location and filename
    print('Location:', f)
    print('File Name:', f.split("\\")[-1])
      
    # print the content
    print('Content:')
    display(df)
    print()
```

Answer (score 2):

It's easier to read and access if you build a dictionary to store your DataFrames in, imo. By creating `ExcelFile` objects first, we can get the sheet names separately, so that we can read all sheets even if we don't know how many there are and what their names are.

```py
import pandas as pd
import os
import glob
import re

path = os.getcwd()
csv_files = glob.glob(os.path.join(path, "*.xlsx"))

files = {}
for f in csv_files:
    file = pd.ExcelFile(f)
    c_id = re.findall(r'.\\(\d+)\w+', f)[0]
    for sn in file.sheet_names:
        key = "c{}_{}".format(c_id, sn)
        files[key] = file.parse(sheet_name=f"{sn}")
```

This creates a dictionary of 1000 DataFrames. Then to access sheet5 of 1CompanyA.xlsx, you can use `files['c1_sheet5']`, etc.

Now if you insist on creating a variable named `c1_sheet5` etc., one way is to use `globals()`:

```py
for f in csv_files:
    file = pd.ExcelFile(f)
    c_id = re.findall(r'.\\(\d+)\w+', f)[0]
    for sn in file.sheet_names:
        key = "c{}_{}".format(c_id, sn)
        globals()[key] = file.parse(sheet_name=f"{sn}")
```

This creates 1000 DataFrames. Then to access sheet5 of 1CompanyA.xlsx, you can use `c1_sheet5`, etc. Note that using `globals()` is considered a bad idea (I can't find a link but there are numerous discussion about it on SO). The gist of it is, `globals` implicitly creates global variables which require dictionary notation; so it's better to build an explicit dictionary like `files` as created above instead.

Comment: @Jiamei Great. So I take it your question is resolved?

Comment: Yes, @enke! Thank you for answering all of my followup questions!

Comment: Looks good to me. Thanks!